# Inserting images along an SVG path in an HTML Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Using an HTML5 canvas element, I'm attempting to draw lights in a specific (/arbitrary) pattern.

If I have an SVG path of the pattern, is it possible to repeatedly step a fixed distance along the path (either based on a fraction of the total length or just a constant distance), and draw an element (either a predefined image or just a basic canvas shape)?

Everything I've got so far is based on placing the elements along arcs of decreasing radius to produce a conical shape, but this no longer matches up with what I need to produce.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) interface still doesn't have a [`getPointAtLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) nor a [`getTotalLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength) method available, so we have to use an `SVGPathElement` to do this for us:

```js
const pathData = `M20 20
                  s 20,80 40,80
                  Q 25,25 40,50
                  t 30,0 30,0 30,0 30,0 30,0
                  M10,30 A20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q90,60 50,90 Q10,60 10,30 z`;
// Create an <SVG:path> element to get the path length
// and the various points at a given distance
const pathEl = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
pathEl.setAttribute("d", pathData);
const totalLength = pathEl.getTotalLength();

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path = new Path2D(pathData);

let duration = 5000;
const begin = performance.now();

const anim = (now) => {
  const delta = ((now - begin) % duration) / duration;
  const distance = delta * totalLength;
  const pt = pathEl.getPointAtLength(distance);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke(path);
  ctx.fillRect(pt.x - 5, pt.y - 5, 10, 10);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
};
requestAnimationFrame(anim);
```

```html
<canvas height=500></canvas>
```

but this means you must have access to the DOM, i.e no support in Worker.

Otherwise, you can try to implement this yourself, but honestly that's not that easy...
But I got you covered since this is actually part of the features I wanted to add to my [Path2D-inspection prototype](https://github.com/Kaiido/path2D-inspection) and that [someone else](https://github.com/rveciana/svg-path-properties) already did the hard-work.

So using this prototype of mine we can directly use a `Path2D` object, and this should work in a `Worker` too:

```js
const pathData = `M20 20
                  s 20,80 40,80
                  Q 25,25 40,50
                  t 30,0 30,0 30,0 30,0 30,0
                  M10,30 A20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q90,60 50,90 Q10,60 10,30 z`;

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path = new Path2D(pathData);
const totalLength = path.getTotalLength();

let duration = 5000;
const begin = performance.now();

const anim = (now) => {
  const delta = ((now - begin) % duration) / duration;
  const distance = delta * totalLength;
  const pt = path.getPointAtLength(distance);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke(path);
  ctx.fillRect(pt.x - 5, pt.y - 5, 10, 10);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
};
requestAnimationFrame(anim);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/path2D-inspection@master/build/path2D-inspection.min.js"></script>
<canvas height=500></canvas>
```

Hopefully we'll be able to add these methods directly to the `Path2D` interface in a near future. But speccing all this and getting traction from implementers will be a long race.